# How do you create a sequence of modalViewControllers?

Tags: modal-dialog, about-box

I have struggled and now I just need to see it in action.  I have an info-button on my title page (UIViewController) and I want to bring up an About-view with a 'dismiss' button on the left and a 'detail disclosure on the right.'  If one presses the 'detail disclosure', it brings up the PrivacyStatement-view with the same buttons.  If one presses the 'detail disclosure', it will bring up a Credits-view.  I should be able to continue this for additional Legal, etc.

According to the Apple doc's one dismiss will dismiss the entire sequence, regardless of where one is at the time.

I have been able to get the views to show, but they won't dismiss themselves.  These leads me to think that I am not using the preferred approach but rather, I have developed an ad-hoc approach that leaves me with dangling structures.

Any suggestions?  I have my thoughts, but I am only one two levels deep and the dismiss doesn't work! :(  I have a total dead-end and have to Quit the app to get back on the real App view.

Comment: Hey ... this question has earned me the Tumbleweed badge ... that isn't good.  No one has answered or even commented.  Is this question really obscure or does everyone already know the answer??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!  Basically, the code is cascaded along the 'workflow' of viewcontrollers.  I devised a style where most of the technical class management is done by the tools and leaves me with book keeping and content.  I will need some review for memory management, as I think my current code is probably leaking controllers up and down the path.  Also, the fact that I can traverse back and forth leads me to think that I really just have a stack of views and not modal views.  I will post the code sometime by the end of the week.